# Split column after specified number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
TEST <- data.frame(
  Segment = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
  Value = c("0", "0", "0","1", "1", "1"))
```

Which results in the following:

```
Row #   Segment  Value
1       A        0
2       A        0
3       A        0
4       B        1
5       B        1
6       B        1
```

How can I change this into a dataframe like this?

```
Row # Segment   Value  Segment Value
1      A        0      B       1 
2      A        0      B       1
3      A        0      B       1
```

The number of observations is equal for each segment and is set by an integer in R (which I call "obs"). So, I want a general line of code to create this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That looks like you are trying to switch from usable format to completely unsable/unworkable format. I would keep the data in a long format if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
do.call(cbind,split(TEST, TEST$Segment))

 # A.segment A.value B.segment B.value
 # A         0       B         1      
 # A         0       B         1      
 # A         0       B         1
```

I hope this helps.